# Deck/platform over hot tub

Tags: wood, design, safety, strength, measurement

[image][enter image description here]

Hope it's okay to post here. What I'd like to build is kinda like a deck.

We have a hot tub (6.5 ft x 7ft) that we don't use. Currently, doesn't work (might fix it sometime in the future).

I'd like to build a deck/platform above it so we can use the extra 45 square feet the platform will provide. The lips of the hot tub (the edges that sit on the floor) protrude 2". I'm trying to minimize the height of the platform as much as possible.

My 1st option is 2x8s around the hot tub and then 2x6s as joists across the 6.5ft span 16" OC. This will give me a height of 7.5" not including the plywood and carpet that'll go on top.

My 2nd option is 2x6s around the hot tub and then 2x4s as joists across the 6.5ft span 16" OC (or 12" OC if recommended). This will give me a height of 5.5" not including the plywood and carpet that'll go on top.

This room will primarily be a gym. So, we'll most probably have a treadmill and exercise bike on the platform.

Just curious what you guys/gals think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. *"Just curious what you guys/gals think."* This is a little too open-ended for the SE model. We're here, as much as possible, to provide tightly focussed Answers to concrete queries, and there actually is no question here at all..... if you can modify it to actually ask something specific go ahead, but this sounds like it would be a better fit for a standard forum format where you can e.g. get some feedback, then get into an exchange with one or more respondents to iron out details.

Comment: the 2x4's are plenty of strength, and you could probably do even better buy using 2x2 across the tub you could use 3/4" ply to stiffen it all up.  as long as you aren't dropping your weights on it or other extreme impacts it would be fine.

Comment: @bowlturner American Wood Council deck calculator says that spruce/pine/fir 2x4 @16"oc can span 6'1" so 2x2 will be inadequate.

Comment: @ksn It would be best if the bearing ends of this new deck rest upon multiple joists of the original deck, so orient your framing accordingly.

Comment: If the actual height of the lip is 2”, then the combination of 2x4 (3.5 actual) and 2x6 (5.25 actual) will require padding underneath the 2x6. Otherwise, this will probably work. I’d suggest 3/4 decking at a minimum; maybe price out 1-1/8” just to see. And if there’s no room for a 2x6 between the tub and the walls, strongly suggest a ledger and joist hangers, rather than resting on the lip.

Comment: @Ashlar thanks for the info!